# Why Count function is not working on this sub query?

Tags: sql, derby, javadb

This:

[image]

outputs following:

[image]

Now I want to apply count function on above table, for that I executed following query.

```
select count(date1) from (
select date1 from tmp where 
current_date > date1
);
```

And got this error:

> Error code 20000, SQL state 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered ""
> at line 4, column 1.

**Note: I am using Java DB**

Comment: @JoaozitoPolo still getting the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sub query usually needs an alias, try

```
 select count(date1) from (
   select date1 from tmp where 
   current_date > date1
 ) a ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know JavaDb, but try giving your nested select statement an alias:

Select count(*) cnt from (select date1 from tmp where current_date > date1) a